# How to answer next prompt based on result of previous prompt nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux

I used child_process for doing some command line stuff.
I know I can pass parameters to a command  like this `echo 'y\ny' | ...`,
but my problem is that I want to pass the second parameter based on the result of the first param. How can I do it in nodejs?

Example

```
echo '1\n?' | 'run some command';
run some command
1) get users
2) ....
enter a number: 1
1) first user
2) second user
select user:?
```

I want to know how after answering the first prompt get the id of user based on text search on the result of the first answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using expect command in linux. I wrote script file and executed it inside nodejs

https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect